# Newly installed 20.04.3 LTS with 5.13.0-27 kernel?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kernel

I have two Dell laptops:

1. Laptop A ( Dell laptop ) which was upgraded to 20.04.3 LTS a year or so ago from 18.04.x LTS. This has:

```
Linux 5.4.0-96-generic #109-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 16:49:16 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2. Laptop B, a new Dell laptop which had Windows11 and wiped it out with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS installed from a live USB. During the install, I selected the option to upgrade automatically from the repositories. This new latop have the following kernel :

```
Linux 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Both of the above laptops have :

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```

Both also have livepatch enabled.

The question is: What am I missing that as to why does laptop A ( in item [1] ) never upgrades the kernel to 5.13.x like what laptop B have when laptop B is freshly installed ?

I literally type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

... everyday on laptop A. Although it upgrades to the latest 5.4.x kernel ... never upgrades to 5.13.x kernel.

Comment: It's https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Useful as well @Someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu LTS releases have two main kernel stack choices

**GA or the general kernel stack**

This *kernel stack* remains the same for the life of the product. For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it will use the 5.4 kernel.

**HWE or hardware enablment stack**

This *kernel stack* will change as the release advances.

At

- 20.04.2 it uses the 5.8 kernel stack from Ubuntu 20.10
- 20.04.3 it uses the 5.11 kernel stack from Ubuntu 21.04
- 20.04.4 it uses the 5.13 kernel stack from Ubuntu 21.10  (*20.04 or focal is progressing to 20.04.4 currently with some of the packages already installed*)
- 20.04.5 will use the 5.15 kernel stack from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (the GA stack for 22.04).

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details.

Ubuntu Server installs default to the more *stable* GA stack, but it can be changed at install, and post-install.

Ubuntu Desktop installs default to the HWE stack by default, but can be changed post-install.

Ubuntu *flavors* can vary depending on media; I'll use Lubuntu 20.04 as example.

- Lubuntu 20.04 & 20.04.1 media defaults to GA kernel stack for new installs
- Lubuntu 20.04.2 & later media defaults to HWE kernel stack for new installs.

Other OEM kernel stacks can also be used for new installs; if the installer detects your hardware as benefiting from an OEM kernel.

You can have both kernel stacks (GA & HWE) installed on a system as well; meaning you'll have more to upgrade (*both will get updates*), but the bandwidth & disk space used isn't that great; you select at boot (ie. `grub`) which you'll use. However do note some *closed-source* or proprietary video drivers do **not** allow both stacks to co-exist.

Refer to the provided wiki page how to install/switch installs; eg. to switch from HWE to GA (for Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS) search for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*"

Comment: Maybe also add how to replace the GA stack with the HWE stack.

Comment: It's covered in the wiki I provided... Yeah this site does like being a 'goto' for howto's... but I'd prefer to point to the official doc instead (ie. when changes are made; official docs are changed; sites like this tend to *trail* & become dated.. thus my preference to point where to find the info officially).  @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: Thanks! So I managed to install the HWE stack during install from live USB without even realising it. I do recall selecting the option to install any proprietary drivers, which ended up using creating a MOK signature for SecureBoot ad this new laptop B has an nVidia discrete GPU while laptop A has an AMD Radeon discrete GPU. Although this new install on laptop B simply seems to have used the nouveau drivers instead.

Comment: I now have the older laptop ( laptop A ) now also use HWE stack ( 5.13.0-27 ) with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Thanks all !

Comment: I'm on ```Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS```, and have had to boot into *5.11.0-43-generic* because 5.13.0-27-generic and 5.13.0-28-generic gave me issues and are missing from when I boot entries. How can I get into 28?

Comment: @chx101  I'd ask your own question, as I don't see how it relates to this question & particularly the answer I gave on kernel stacks. The 5.11 kernel was [EOL months ago](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) with 20.04 systems upgrading about then too ([or weeks before 20.04.4's ISO release date](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/)) so your issue can't have just occurred, but makes little sense in relation to this answer anyway.